# What is the best way to store multiple user data in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm trying to make a table to store the user's weight per month (over the course of 12 months), what is the best approach to this if I want to store multiple user datas, because every month the weight is different.

Comment: User table; user weights table.  user weights records userId, weight, date and has a composite key on userID and date.  that way you can record all users data and any # of months and let the app limit it to 12 if desired.  However best is subjective so it depends on overall goals  but it seems a user could have multiple weights on different periods so a 1:M relationship seemed logical.

Comment: do you need to allow for multiple units of measure on weights?  (kg, lbs, tons, etc)

Comment: @xQbert no its just the weight. Right now I already have the userID as a foreign key taken from another table (```user``` table). I wanted to store the user and the weight for each month and create a chart out of that data for an individual user

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should have some way of identifying users, let's say you have a unique `user_id`. Then your table could look like this:

```
user_id | month   | weight
--------------------------
1       | 03/2019 |  76.54
1       | 04/2019 |  75.32
2       | 03/2019 | 103.12
2       | 04/2019 |  97.84
```

In that table you can store any amount of records for the same user. If you want to make sure that each user can only have one measurement per month, you can add a unique index for the columns `user_id` and `month` combined.

Any other information about the users like their name and email address have to be stored in a separate table, because you only want to store them once per user. You should also define a foreign key constraint on the column `user_id` to tell the database application that each weight record references a user record.

Comment: Thanks, will consider this approach